# scipy.misc.imread() working on windows but not linux

Tags: python, scipy

My script goes something like this:

```
from scipy import misc
pic = misc.imread(path_to_image)
```

It works on my Windows machine but not when I run it on a linux machine. I get the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'imread'`.

Reading some other similar questions, I have confirmed that scipy is is installed, and so is Pillow. I'm running a virtualenv with python 3.3.2, and have run other scripts successfully there.

Comment: This should work under linux as well. Looks like your scipy installation is broken. I would try to reinstall and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Just a guess: you probably need to install Pillow before installing scipy.

Comment: Thanks. Upgrading Pillow solved the problem.